# Hide a dropdown menu OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown menu, one of the options executes Ajax to show data in another Div.

I want to hide the dropdown menu (close it) when this option is clicked.

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-floating" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="ti-more-alt"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" >
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"   data-sidebar-target="#view-detail"  onclick="return onclickFunction('<?php echo $master_repository_id ?>');">View Folder Details</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Share Folder via Email</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Rename Folder</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Delete Folder</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have tried the below which I found online, but it doesn't seem to close the menu:

```
// hide the menu when an example is clicked
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   debugger;
   var ele=$(".dropdown-content");
   
   $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(){
     if(this.innerText=="Link 2"){
      $(".dropdown-content").hide();
      $(".dropbtn").hide();
     }
     
   });

});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You hide a dropdown menu like this and if you want to show simply add show functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this toggle method should work

```
<a href="#" onclick="handleClick()"  class="btn btn-floating" data-toggle="dropdown">
    how/hide menu
</a>

function handleClick(){
    
   $(".dropdown-menu").toggle(); 
    
}
```

refer to this link for running example:

https://playcode.io/647558/

Comment: what is your jquery version ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove class 'show' from dropdown:

```
// hide the menu when an example is clicked
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function(el){
    $(el.target).parents(".dropdown").removeClass("show"); 
});
```

Comment: Tried this too - it doesnt do anything?